# Azure VNET location is not shown; cannot create new VM in existing VNET

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I created a VNET a few days ago. Then added there two virtual machines and everything was running smoothly until today when I had to add a third VM.

I did everything exactly same like previous two times but creation of new VM failed and I had to start from the beginning. Unfortunately when I got to a third step (where VNET has to be specified) Azure UI told me that there are no VNETs available in selected region (West Europe): 
[image]

But here is what I see in "All resources" list:
[image]

And here is properties of "frontend-vnet":
[image]

By some reason "Location" is not shown there (which is a clear bug).

I guess, my VNET got corrupted but I don't see the way how to fix it. Did somebody encounter same situation? Does somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: This seems like an internal Azure issue, it is probably best to raise a support ticket with them. (since I am sure its not a setting that you've neglected somewhere)

Comment: As we are using BizSpark program, I cannot raise a support ticket. But I posted a question on MSDN forum and tweeted to their support. Lets see how it goes :)

Comment: You get free support tickets with BizSpark you have to register it via the help and support blade in the portal

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that. Now I tried to link my BizSpark account but I haven't succeeded. After clicking on "Link" button I see "Linking Contract..." text but nothing happens. Probably that's just not my day :)

Comment: Have you tried to create the vm with Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI? It's probably not an internal Azure issue but a problem of the Ibiza portal. Try to create the vm with some other methods, and see what happen next.

Comment: @JackZeng I tried directly on Azure portal. It might be that PowerShell would function as expected. Today everything started working as before. I hoe there will be no second time :) but in case if it happens, I will test PowerShell as well and update this question